# Google tag manager with enhanced ecommerce, but no ecommerce data in analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement the google tag managers UA Ecommerce features.

I've followed all steps from https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce.

According to the Google Analytics quick preview all my tags are being send with the DataLayer to GTM, but the ecommerce data isn't visible in Google Analytics.

Example tag im sending to GTM:

```
{
 "ecommerce":{
  "detail":{
   "actionField":{
    "list":"Product Page"
   },
   "products":
    [
     {
      "name":"Twin Time",
      "brand":"Fromanteel",
      "price":"499.00",
      "category":"watch"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
```

I know the normal analytics works, since i do receive sessions.

Website in question: https://fromanteel.nl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the pushes to the dataLayer succeed. I'm guessing that the corresponding tag might not be triggered. Actually had this happen to me a few weeks ago :-)

In the Tag Manager settings, under tags > your specific tag(s), verify that the trigger fires on everything that applies. For example, select 'all pages' and 'clicks' (not just the first).

I suggest using preview mode to see if the tag actually triggers.

Comment: Face, meet desk... not sure how i missed that, thanks!